# Error in deleting records when load on server increases?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table summary which has a column status .The table already has data with status 1. Firstly I am inserting new records into table with status equal to 0. Then 
I am deleting old records with status 1 and the finally updating records with status 0 to 1.
It is working fine when server load is less but when load increases, old records(status 1) are not deleting and new records(status 0) gets inserted and updated to 1.

Following is the fow-

1.saveAndFlush new records with status 0.

2.deleteRecords();

3.updateRecords();

The query for delete is

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM TableDataSummary  t where t.status=1")
public void deleteSummary();
```

And for update -

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "Update TableDataSummary t  set t.status=1")
public   void updateSummary();
```

This is happening randomly, how to resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell from the queries alone. It could be a locking issue, it could be a timing issue, ... - btw, you should work on your naming scheme, i.e. `deleteSummary()` vs. `UpdateSummary()` - the Java code conventions would favor `updateSummary()` to reduce confusion between methods and constructors.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced something like that recently. I had to provide a CRUD functionnality to manipulate data from the database. I used JPA also and for the update functionnality, I didn't use  update query directly in my Repository. 
If it may help you, I'll share my idea: 
1. saveAndFlush new records with status 0. 
2.deleteRecords();
3. do a findAll() from your Controller to get all the data (normally, you should only get data with status = 0 , because you have just deleted the others with status = 1.) 
4. create a loop to get access to each data of the result of the "findAll()" 
5. inside the loop, you have to set "status" to "1" and call "save()" for each object. 

And "save()" will update the data automatically

hope that it will help you, otherwise maybe I missunderstood you.